# SQL Inner JOIN with query

Tags: sql, activerecord, arel

I am trying to do something like this but I am not sure if you can do this with a inner join:

```
SELECT "scores".* 
FROM "scores" 
    INNER JOIN "games" ON "games"."id" = "scores"."games_id" 
WHERE 
    "games"."date" >= '2013-02-11 19:30:11.799227' 
AND "scores".value > 350;
```

Thanks for the help. Also, if you know how to write a ActiveRecord / arel statement the would give the query that would be helpful as well.

My models look like this:

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  delegates :date, to: game
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: The SQL syntax is just fine, and should work correctly. Did you test it?

Comment: What do you mean by "ActiveRecord/arel" statement?

Comment: @DavidW, he is talking about about relational algebra queries commonly used with ruby on rails

Comment: @rs Doh on me. Thanks...can't help on that, sadly :(

Comment: Note that it's usually best to put as many relevant relations as possible in a `JOIN` clause - depending on your database, this may be automatically performed in the case of `INNER JOIN`s (sort-of).  Among other things, it makes `LEFT JOIN`s clear.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski When I run the above statement it says `ERROR: relation 'games' does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveRecord query would look like this:

```
some_date = DateTime.parse('2013-02-11 19:30:11.799227')
score = 350
Score.joins(:game).
      where("games.date >= ? AND scores.value > ?", some_date, score)
```

This assumes that you have `belongs_to :game` in your Score model.

Comment: This does not seem to work, I get the error `PG::Error Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table 'games'

Comment: @trev9065: Do you have a `Game` model? And what is `Workout`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is a Game model.

Comment: @trev9065: Can you add `.to_sql` to the end of the ActiveRecord query and post the output?  And did you run your migration that creates your 'games' table?

Comment: Yes I am sure I have the table because I already have other relations built on the table and it is only this one method that is giving me errors. Here is the output: `"SELECT \"scores\".* FROM \"scores\" INNER JOIN \"games\" ON \"games\".\"id\" = \"scores\".\"game_id\" WHERE (games.date >= '2013-02-11 21:16:13.824959' AND scores.value > 350)"`

Comment: So the query generated is the one you were looking for.  The error message `relation 'games' does not exist` seems to indicate that it can't find this table - can you double check using PGAdmin?

Comment: Double checked \d gives me  scores and games tables, the scores table has the correct columns (game_id and value) and the games table has a date column.

Comment: Can you check that this database is the same as your console (or server environment)?  That is, you aren't looking at your development db, while running the code against your test db...  Besides that the errors are inconsistent (`missing FROM-clause` vs `relations 'games' does not exist`), the second error seems to indicate that the database can't find the table.